# Python folium Clickformarker - 2 functions don't collaborate with each other

Tags: python, folium

I would like to use the folium.CLickFormarker macro more than once in my map. Unfortunately it doesn't work, as my function takes only the first one.

```
fs=folium.FeatureGroup(name="Surveyors")

df = pd.read_csv("survey.csv")

class Circle(folium.ClickForMarker):
_template = Template(u"""
        {% macro script(this, kwargs) %}
            var circle_job = L.circle();
            function newMarker(e){
                circle_job.setLatLng(e.latlng).addTo({{this._parent.get_name()}});
                circle_job.setRadius(50000);
                circle_job.bringToFront();
                };
            {{this._parent.get_name()}}.on('click', newMarker);      
        {% endmacro %}
        """)  # noqa

 def __init__(self, popup=None):
    super(Circle, self).__init__()
    self._name = 'Circle'

 job_range2 = Circle()


 class ClickForOneMarker(folium.ClickForMarker):
   _template = Template(u"""
        {% macro script(this, kwargs) %}
            var new_mark = L.marker();
            function newMarker(e){
                new_mark.setLatLng(e.latlng).addTo({{this._parent.get_name()}});
                new_mark.setZIndexOffset(-1);
                new_mark.on('dblclick', function(e){
                {{this._parent.get_name()}}.removeLayer(e.target)})
                var lat = e.latlng.lat.toFixed(4),
                   lng = e.latlng.lng.toFixed(4);
                new_mark.bindPopup("<a href=https://www.google.com/maps?layer=c&cbll=" + lat + "," + lng + " target=blank><img src=img/streetview.svg width=150 title=StreetView></img></a>")//.openPopup();
                };
            {{this._parent.get_name()}}.on('click', newMarker);      
        {% endmacro %}
        """)  # noqa

def __init__(self, popup=None):
    super(ClickForOneMarker, self).__init__()
    self._name = 'ClickForOneMarker'


click_for_marker = ClickForOneMarker()

map.add_child(click_for_marker)

for i,row in df.iterrows():
lat =df.at[i, 'lat']
lng = df.at[i, 'lng']
sp = df.at[i, 'sp']
phone = df.at[i, 'phone']
role = df.at[i, 'role']
rad = int(df.at[i, 'radius'])

popup = '<b>Phone: </b>' + str(df.at[i,'phone'])

order_rng = folium.Circle([lat,lng],
        radius=rad * 10.560,           
        popup= df.at[i, 'sp'],
        tooltip = sp + ' - Job limits',
        color='black',
        fill=True,
        fill_color='black',
        opacity=0.1,
        fill_opacity=0.1
      )

if role == 'Contractor':
    fs.add_child(
        folium.Marker(location=[lat,lng],
                  tooltip=folium.map.Tooltip(
                      text='<strong>Contact surveyor</strong>',
                      style=("background-color: lightgreen;")),
                  popup=popup,
                  icon = folium.Icon(color='darkred', icon='glyphicon-user'
                                     )
                )
    )
    fs.add_child (
        folium.Marker(location=[lat,lng],
                  popup=popup,
                  icon = folium.DivIcon(html="<b>" + sp + "</b>",
                                        class_name="mapText_contractor",
                                        icon_anchor=(30,5))
                )
    )
    fs.add_child(job_range)
```

The first one is just what I want to include as the child for the existing feature group. The second one should be applicable to the entire map.
Both don't work when included together. Is it folium limited to one ClickForMarker macro or something?

Answer (score 0):

The primary error was using the same JavaScript function `newMarker(e)`, which created the conflict.
I've provided the other function for my second case and it has started working correctly.

```
class ClickForOneMarker(folium.ClickForMarker):
_template = Template(u"""
        {% macro script(this, kwargs) %}
            var new_mark = L.marker();
            function newMarker(e){
                new_mark.setLatLng(e.latlng).addTo({{this._parent.get_name()}});
                new_mark.setZIndexOffset(-1);
                new_mark.on('dblclick', function(e){
                {{this._parent.get_name()}}.removeLayer(e.target)})
                var lat = e.latlng.lat.toFixed(4),
                   lng = e.latlng.lng.toFixed(4);
                new_mark.bindPopup("<a href=https://www.google.com/maps?layer=c&cbll=" + lat + "," + lng + " target=blank><img src=img/streetview.svg width=150 title=StreetView></img></a>")//.openPopup();
                };
            {{this._parent.get_name()}}.on('click', newMarker);      
        {% endmacro %}
        """)  # noqa

def __init__(self, popup=None):
    super(ClickForOneMarker, self).__init__()
    self._name = 'ClickForOneMarker'


click_for_marker = ClickForOneMarker()

map.add_child(click_for_marker)


class Circle(folium.ClickForMarker):
_template = Template(u"""
        {% macro script(this, kwargs) %}
            var circle_job = L.circle();
            function newCircle(e){
                
circle_job.setLatLng(e.latlng).addTo({{this._parent.get_name()}});
                circle_job.setRadius(50000);
                circle_job.bringToFront();
                };
            {{this._parent.get_name()}}.on('click', newCircle);      
        {% endmacro %}
        """)  # noqa

 def __init__(self, popup=None):
    super(Circle, self).__init__()
    self._name = 'Circle'     

job_range = Circle()
```